# Problems occur when I block a specific user to access Internet using iptables while ufw is enable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

I have enable ufw to reject some in going traffic, only allow port 80,22 to be opened.

And further more, today I need to block specific user to access Internet using iptables rule as follow:

```
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner winguse -j REJECT
```

But it doesn't work!

If I disable ufw, and perform the same action it does work. And if I enable ufw, it doesn't work again.

How could I do?

Answer (score 3):

After asking ufw manual's writer Jamie Strandboge, I have found the answer.

Just edit /etc/ufw/before.rules, add the following line after "# End required lines":

```
-A ufw-before-output -m owner --uid-owner winguse -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

then, reload the firewall by using

```
$ sudo ufw reload
```

and the rules will take effect.